# Not getting the right information (HZ_PARTIES vs HZ_PARTY_SITES)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ebs

**NOTE:** This thread is for those who know Oracle EBS (developers or programmers)

I have been trying to get the contact information that is stored in HZ_PARTIES BUT for some reason it shows NULL emails and thats not correct (my query works just fine if i put HZ_PARTY_SITES instead of HZ_PARTIES, but it is not showing the information that i want)

Everytime that a customers is created, this PROCEDURE is executed:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/9nzMKy4D

Based on the information shown above, i made this query:

```
SELECT
    hp.party_name                              
  , hca.account_number                                           
  , hcp.phone_number
  , hcp.email_address                              
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_site hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON hps.party_id = hp.party_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            owner_table_id
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'PHONE' then phone_number end) phone_number
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'EMAIL' then email_address end) email_address
        FROM hz_contact_points
        WHERE status = 'A'
        AND primary_flag = 'Y'
        AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTIES'
        AND contact_point_type IN ('EMAIL','PHONE')
        GROUP BY 
            owner_table_id
    ) hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id 
WHERE hcas.status = 'A'
AND hps.status = 'A'
AND hca.status = 'A'
--AND hca.account_number = 'account_number'
;
```

Take a look at this image (i cannot upload images yet):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8qvW.jpg)

Could you please help me to solve this?

EDIT: I am connecting to an Oracle Database (11g)

Comment: Hi, a couple of things. 1. This is all about the trading community architecture data model. 2. Look at Sanjai's example of using hz_relationships to get a start at fixing your approach, https://sanjaimisra.blogspot.com/2013/12/customers-phone-email-and-url.html?

Comment: Hey, nice to meet you. Thank you for replying!. Yeah, i tried to modify my query using those queries but it does not work :/. Could you please give me a hand, im lost :(

Comment: Hi, can you update your question to confirm your version of Oracle EBS?

Comment: @PatrickBacon Oracle EBS database version: 11g

Comment: I suspect your contacts are created at the site level and not at the account level. Can you confirm?

Comment: All i know is that ALL customers have contact information at HZ_PARTY_SITES level(ship or bill_to addresses have email and phone number) AND at HZ_PARTIES (they call it HEADER information.. i mean, there you will find the personal email and phone number for every customer). Do you get me?

Comment: @PatrickBacon I dont know how to modify my query or your query in order to obtain what i need.. i am lost :(

Answer (score 0):

**This is all about working with the Trading Community Architecture**

See how the hz_relationships table is used to bring this information in. The below query works for an EBS R12.2 environment (12.1 database) where the contacts are created at the account level (EBS R12 allows both at the account level and the site level,[Customer Form, Contacts/Communication: Troubleshooting, How To, Known Issues and Patches (Doc ID 1456319.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=225286748423396&id=1456319.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=7gdvwd48e_4)).

```
SELECT
    hca.account_number   cust_account_number,
    obj.party_name       customer_name,
    sub.party_name       contact_name,
    hps.party_site_number,
    hcp.contact_point_type,
    hcp.phone_number,
    hcp.email_address
FROM
    apps.hz_cust_accounts         hca
    JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all   hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
    JOIN apps.hz_parties               obj ON hca.party_id = obj.party_id
                                      AND obj.party_type = 'ORGANIZATION'
    JOIN apps.hz_relationships         rel ON hca.party_id = rel.object_id
                                      AND rel.relationship_type = 'CONTACT'
                                      AND rel.directional_flag = 'F'
    JOIN apps.hz_parties               sub ON rel.subject_id = sub.party_id
                                       AND sub.party_type = 'PERSON'
    JOIN apps.hz_contact_points        hcp ON rel.party_id = hcp.owner_table_id
                                       AND hcp.owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTIES'
    JOIN apps.hz_party_sites           hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
    JOIN apps.hz_locations             hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
WHERE
    hcas.status = 'A'
    AND hps.status = 'A'
    AND hca.status = 'A'
    AND hcp.contact_point_type IN (
        'PHONE',
        'EMAIL'
    )
ORDER BY
    2,
    3
 ;
```

---

This query looks at contacts which are set-up at the site level (customer contacts):

```
SELECT
    hca.account_number   cust_account_number,
    obj.party_name       customer_name,
    sub.party_name       contact_name,
    hps.party_site_number,
    hcp.contact_point_type,
    hcp.phone_number,
    hcp.email_address
FROM
    apps.hz_cust_accounts         hca
    JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all   hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
    JOIN apps.hz_party_sites           hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
    JOIN apps.hz_locations             hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
    JOIN apps.hz_parties               obj ON hps.party_id = obj.party_id
                                AND obj.party_type = 'ORGANIZATION'
    JOIN apps.hz_relationships         rel ON rel.object_id = obj.party_id
                                      AND rel.relationship_type = 'CONTACT'
                                      AND rel.directional_flag = 'F'
    JOIN apps.hz_parties               sub ON rel.subject_id = sub.party_id
                                AND sub.party_type = 'PERSON'
    JOIN apps.hz_contact_points        hcp ON rel.party_id = hcp.owner_table_id
                                       AND hcp.owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTIES'
WHERE
    hcas.status = 'A'
    AND hps.status = 'A'
    AND hca.status = 'A'
    AND hcp.contact_point_type IN (
        'PHONE',
        'EMAIL'
    )
ORDER BY
    2,
```

---

Boiling down the query a little further, one could just focus on the contact information without focussing on the type of contact:

```
 SELECT
        obj.party_name,
        sub.party_name   contact_name,
        hcp.contact_point_type,
        hcp.phone_number,
        hcp.email_address
    FROM
        apps.hz_parties          obj
        JOIN apps.hz_relationships    rel ON rel.object_id = obj.party_id
                                          AND rel.relationship_type = 'CONTACT'
                                          AND rel.directional_flag = 'F'

        JOIN apps.hz_parties          sub ON rel.subject_id = sub.party_id
        JOIN apps.hz_contact_points   hcp ON rel.party_id = hcp.owner_table_id
                                           AND hcp.owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTIES'
    WHERE
        1 = 1
        AND hcp.contact_point_type IN (
            'PHONE',
            'EMAIL'
        )
    ORDER BY
        2,
        3;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I think that there is a problem. Even with your query i was not able to obtain the information required. Take a look at my query: if i use this conditions: *hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id* instead of this one: *hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id* i get the information but it is repeated and i think it is not correct

Comment: Seriously, i dont understand how to solve this problem, i dont know how to modify my query, this is annoying :(

Comment: @Do note that when i use this condition in my query: *hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id* i got several results for a single customer (so, i got the correct email but its strange because it shows that a customer has multiple different emails and thatS WRONG!)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response: If i use your last query it does not the email that i am looking for :(. I think something is missing

Comment: I dont know why but your last query returns 27 records and it should return several :/

Comment: Dude, have you got any idea?

Comment: Hi, it sounds like the last query returns records, though the count is different than you expect. I checked the joins and the record count and it looks correct (from an R12 EBS perspective. You have also indicated that your contacts are set-up at the site level (query 2 shoud address that). I would try to modify the last query to encapsulate all of your contacts. Pick some that are not showing up and understand the joins between `hz_contact_points` and the other TCA tables. It apparent that your configuration of EBS in this area (and the differences in version) make this harder to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The list of contact points in Party and Party Site level with type as Email and Phone number.

```
SELECT DISTINCT hp.party_id, 
                   hp.party_name,
                   hca.cust_account_id,
                   hca.account_number,
                   party_site_id,
                   party_site_number,
                   hcp.phone_number,
                   NVL (hcp.email_address, hcp.url) email_or_url,
                   hcp.contact_point_type communication_type,
                   hcp.status active,
                   hcp.contact_point_purpose purpose
     FROM apps.hz_contact_points hcp,
          apps.hz_party_sites hps,
          apps.hz_cust_accounts hca,
          apps.hz_parties hp
    WHERE     hps.party_id = hca.party_id
          AND hp.party_id = hca.party_id
          AND hcp.contact_point_type IN ('PHONE','EMAIL') 
          AND hcp.owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTIES'
          AND hcp.owner_table_id = hps.party_id
          AND hcp.status = 'A'
          AND hps.status = 'A'
          AND hca.status = 'A'
          AND hp.status = 'A'
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT hp.party_id, 
                   hp.party_name,
                   hca.cust_account_id,
                   hca.account_number,
                   party_site_id,
                   party_site_number,
                   hcp.phone_number,
                   NVL (hcp.email_address, hcp.url) email_or_url,
                   hcp.contact_point_type communication_type,
                   hcp.status active,
                   hcp.contact_point_purpose purpose
     FROM apps.hz_contact_points hcp,
          apps.hz_party_sites hps,
          apps.hz_cust_accounts hca,
          apps.hz_parties hp
    WHERE     hps.party_id = hca.party_id
          AND hp.party_id = hca.party_id
          AND hcp.contact_point_type IN ('PHONE','EMAIL') 
          AND hcp.owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
          AND hcp.owner_table_id = hps.party_site_id
          AND hcp.status = 'A'
          AND hps.status = 'A'
          AND hp.status = 'A'
          AND hca.status = 'A';
```